# Dúvida básica JavaScript: Como mudar um atributo de um objeto?

Tags: javascript

Acabei me deparando com uma situação meio diferente e fiquei na dúvida.

Gostaria de saber o  seguinte​, eu tenho um array de objetos e em cada objeto tenho dois atributos nele  `{valor: "texto",  tamanho: "médio" }`.

Eu gostaria de criar um novo array utilizando o map por exemplo e gostaria que nesse meu novo array eu alterasse o nome do atributo tamanho para medida.

Como faço para criar esse novo array porém em vez dos atributos de cada objeto serem   (valor e tamanho)   eles serem  (valor e medida)   ?

Comment: Coloque o código do que já fez, assim podemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Como faço para colocar o código aqui ?   no comentário  ele nao deixou pq ultrapassou a quantidade de  caracteres.

Comment: Use o botão editar. Além disso, selecione o código e clique no botão que tem uma chave abrindo e uma fechando para formatar o codigo.

Answer (score 5):

Podes fazer isso com o `.map` como referiste. O código seria assim:

```js
const lista = [{
  valor: "azul",
  tamanho: "grande"
}, {
  valor: "verde",
  tamanho: "pequeno"
}, {
  valor: "branco",
  tamanho: "medio"
}];

function usarMedida(arr) {
  return arr.map(obj => {
    return {
      valor: obj.valor,
      medida: obj.tamanho
    };
  });
}

console.log(usarMedida(lista));
```

Se o objeto for mais complexo do que aquele que tens na pergunta podes fazer assim:

```js
const lista = [{
  valor: "azul",
  tamanho: "grande"
}, {
  valor: "verde",
  tamanho: "pequeno"
}, {
  valor: "branco",
  tamanho: "medio"
}];

function usarMedida(arr) {
  return arr.map(entry => {
    return Object.keys(entry).reduce((obj, key) => {
      const value = entry[key]; // ler o valor
      if (key === 'tamanho') key = 'medida'; // mudar o nome da chave
      obj[key] = value;
      return obj;
    }, {});
  });
}

console.log(usarMedida(lista));
```

Answer (score 4):

Para realizar essa "mudança", você pode criar um atributo novo e remover o velho.

Dessa forma:

```
lista = [ {valor: "azul", tamanho: "grande"}, {valor: "verde", tamanho: "pequeno"}, {valor: "branco", tamanho: "medio"} ];

lista.forEach(function(value) {
    value.medida = value.tamanho;
    delete value.tamanho;
});

console.log( lista );
```

Comment: Mas isso altera o array original, o que não vai de encontro ao que a pergunta indica, "Eu gostaria de criar um novo array ..."

Comment: Isso já é o suficiente para o que preciso fazer !!!  Obrigado Valdeir !

Answer (score 0):

Você está no caminho certo, o método `map` serve para você acessar os índices de uma array e transforma-los em um outro valor. No seu caso, a abordagem para faze-lo é bem simples:

```
const lista = [ {valor: "azul", tamanho: "grande"}, {valor: "verde", tamanho: "pequeno"}, {valor: "branco", tamanho: "medio"} ]
const mapped = lista.map(({valor, tamanho}) => ({ valor, medida: tamanho }))
```

Caso queira encapsular essa solução para reutilizar de forma funcional:

```
// função que trasforma um determinado objeto
const sizeToMesure = ({valor, tamanho}) => ({ valor, medida: tamanho })

// curry function que recebe um mapper e retorna um map
const remapWith = mapper => src => src.map(mapper)

// cria um novo mapper a partir de uma function de transformação
const remapIn = remapWith(sizeToMesure)

// Ao executar este método em uma array, ele a trasforma em uma nova
remapIn(lista) // Array [{...},{...},...
```